# Css div window in a div window's center

Tags: css, html, center

I have a main div at the center of the screen at the shape of the touch pad.
Within it I have another div in which I want to display output. However, the pad itself is set on % to react on different resolutions.

See the pic below, yellow window is the whole pad and the red window is the content screen.

Now I want to make that red window exactly as the pad's screen is set on % so it could adapt on different resolutions, is there a simple way of doing that?

[image]

Yellow's css:

```
#mainWindow{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-image:url("../images/mainWindow.png");
    background-size:100% 100%;
    height:100%;
    width:80%;
    position: relative;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:3px;
    border-color:yellow;
}
```

The red one doesn't really have anything.

I hope you understood me. Thanks beforehand.

**EDIT:**

html code for the screens:

```
<div id='mainWindow'>

        <div id='screen'>



        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it depends also on the structure of your HTML. How red and yellow boxes are correlate to each other?

Comment: can you make a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) example?

Comment: Add padding to `#screen` which matches the bezel on your image.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan after seeing your comment I've realised that I need to count how much % do I need to put on padding, sometimes obvious answers are just by your nose, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly confusing prompt, but see if this works for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/T3MHZ/

HTML snippet:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id='mainWindow'>
            <div id='screen'></div>
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>​
```

CSS styles:

```
html, body{
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}

#mainWindow{
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    /* SET THE PADDING TO THE PX MEASURE OF THE TABLET BORDER */
    padding:50px 40px 50px 40px; 
    /* box sizing will make sure that the usable content size is minus the padding value */
    box-sizing:border-box; 
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid black;
}

#screen{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid red;   
}
```

By using a combination of measured padding on #mainWindow to account for the tablet border, and box sizing of border-box to assure exact fit of the #screen content, this should give you the flexible layout you're looking for.

Don't forget your viewport meta tag! ;)
​

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your answer. Just linking to an external site that can go away anytime will not help future readers.

Answer (score 3):

In order for a DIV to have 100% height, you need to make its parents 100% height as well:

```
body, html {height:100%}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding what you want correctly, but try 
         height: 100%; 
on red.

Comment: I want the red one to be exactly at the center of the yellow one, to be of the size as the blue window is, in other words, to fit in exactly

Comment: Have you tried using position: fixed; or position: anchored; for that?

Answer (score 1):

```
min-height:100%;
```

You have no content, it's going 100% of it's parent content. Diodeus's answer would work as well for the same reason, if the body, html are 100% window height then the divs inside will look at that as content.

http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/Jq7xR/

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="outside">
        <div class="inside"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>​

.container{height:250px;width:400px;}
.outside{border:1px solid red; min-height:100%; height:100%;}
.inside{border:1px solid green; min-height:82.5%; margin:5%}
```

To be honest even my brain is struggling with the 82.5% height to get the margins to work right =/ But I do believe that is what you're after.